# FM to get date within accounting period

Tags: abap

I'm searching for FM or BAPI that takes any date as a parameter and returns the date within the accounting period.

I need something which works like this... i.e. Let's say 04/2021 is open as an accounting period.

```
Case1: Input Parameter(2/1/2021) -> return(4/1/2021)
Case2: Input Parameter(4/15/2021) -> return(4/15/2021)
Case3: Input Parameter(6/1/2021) -> return(4/1/2021)
```

Comment: just change the month manually, you don't need FM for this

Comment: FM BAPI_COMPANYCODE_GET_PERIOD will give you the fiscal period and fiscal year for a given booking date. FM G_PERIOD_ALLOWED_CHECK can be used to check whether a period is open. The second FM doesn't return anything but raises PERIOD_NOT_ALLOWED if the period isn't open. You'll still have to adjust the period to find the first open period starting from your initial booking date.

Comment: @DirkTrilsbeek You might want to write that as a proper answer.